# Floats changing when passing them from CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, c++-cli

**EDIT** : i wrote the same code that i had at work at home to recreate the bug. this is the exact code !!

I'm trying to pass floating number from c++ to c# and i'm using c++ CLI as intermediate.
I have the following function in C++ cli

```
void myclass::getFloats(float% f1, float %f2)
{
    float f11=734212.384f;
    float f22=467474.26675f;
    f1=f11;
    f2=f22;
}
```

When i put a break point in the end of the function and stop there, i see that :

- f1 holds : 734212.38
- f2 holds : 467474.28

I assume that it is ok due to floating point limitations.

But then when the scope ends and i return to the c# code that called this function which looks like this :

```
myclass m = new myclass();
float f1=0, f2=0;
m.getFloats(ref f1, ref f2);
```

And i stop after the getFloat function i see that.

- f1 holds 734212.4
- f2 holds 467474.281

I have no clue for why this is happening, why in the first number he rounded up 0.38 to 0.4 and in the second he didn't and just added 0.001 ?

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Because the C++CLI debugger shows only three significant digits (so rounds the value in the display) while the C# have four significant digits in its display of the values?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the C++ and C# debuggers that have different rounding?

Comment: this is not the case, there are situations when i see in the watch 4.79999 in cli and it converts to 4.8 in c#. the watch shows me in the CLI more then 3 digits.

Comment: i not sure about anything.. how can i know while in debug what is the exact number ?

Comment: Please show us real code. I don't think this `float a,b; getFloat(ref a, ref b);` compiles. `a` and `b` are not initialized.

Comment: I rewrote the code at home and posted it :) i can upload the solution to some filesharing website if it will help.

Comment: Note that **["In C# an implicit conversion between `float` and `float` is an identity conversion. An explicit conversion, though, is not an identity conversion"](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/321323639523917825)** #floathatesyou see also: [disassembly listings on paste-bin](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/321408972840112128)

Answer (score 0):

You're up against the limits of precision for 32-bit floating point.  I'd change to `double` and see if your "problems" go away.

The number you have is

```
float f22=467474.26675f;
```

The nearest floating point representation is

```
48E44249   467474.28125
```

The debug displays you're seeing, `"467474.28"` and `"467474.281"`, are both reasonable ways of displaying this value.

The next representable number is

```
48E4424A   467474.3125
```

Your idea expressed in the comments that rounding error is on the order of `0.0000001` is only true for values between 0.5 and 1.0.  In general, roundoff error will be on the order of `0.0000001 * value`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the change happens when the programs finishes the CLI command code and get's back to c# ?
I understand that the rounding should happen in this line : 
float f11=734212.384f; but after the float got the number it shouldn't change. does c++ and c# have different representation of float ?

Comment: @OopsUser: The number isn't changing.  It's still 0x48E44249.  You're just dealing with two different debuggers, which display it slightly differently.  Neither one is showing you the true exact value, which is 467474.28125

Comment: Is there a way to see the exact value while debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by the floating point  mode. In native C++, we can use the compiler option /fp to specify 3 floating modes: [fast, precise,strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx). By default, native C++ project use fp:precise; while according to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/902654ec-a138-4387-9e7c-32b391cba9fe/floating-point-model-want-c-to-be-equivalent-to-fpprecise), managed code use something equivalent to fp:fast. While fp:fast has less precision than fp:precise, i think this is the reason for the problem.

you can try to specify fp:fast in native C++ to see if this problem can be fixed.

Just for your reference, [Microsoft Visual C++ Floating-Point Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289157%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I changed in C++ cli from precise to fast and it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Did you change the settings in the native C++ project?

Comment: I deleted the c++ project, look at my code, i have simple cli that returns constant numbers.